# raggedright and begin{flushleft} having different behaviour

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, overleaf, ragged2e

I am trying align text such that the first line is fully left aligned, and the second line is centered. The following is the desired behaviour with the associated code.

```
\begin{flushleft}
Step 2:
\end{flushleft}
\begin{center}
chi-squared-test (assuming data is normal)
\end{center}
```

[image: correct result]

I usually use `\raggedright` and `\centering` like the following, but this gives me undesirable behaviour.

```
\raggedright{Step 2:}
\centering{chi-squared-test (assuming data is normal)}
```

[image: incorrect result]

I also tried inserting a `\newline` after the first line, but this also gives me undesirable behaviour.

```
\raggedright{Step 2:}
\newline
\centering{chi-squared-test (assuming data is normal)}
```

[image: incorrect result]

I have the working section in the first code block, but in an effort to write less, I would prefer to use `\raggedright` and `\centering` instead. What am I doing incorrectly? Why is the behaviour between the code blocks different? Thanks.

The following is the full document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
Step 2:
\end{flushleft}
\begin{center}
chi-squared-test (assuming data is normal)
\end{center}

\raggedright{Step 2:}
\newline
\centering{chi-squared-test (assuming data is normal)}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\raggedright and \centering don't take an argument. They are switches that affect paragraphs. So you need to group them and end the paragraph first:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
Step 2:
\end{flushleft}
\begin{center}
chi-squared-test (assuming data is normal)
\end{center}

{\raggedright Step 2: \par}

{\centering chi-squared-test (assuming data is normal)\par}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Didn't realize I was using them wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

With `flushleft` followed by `center` you get too much vertical space.

Using `\raggedright` and `\centering` would not add unwanted space, but they aren't commands with argument. There's another aspect to take into account, though: you don't want page breaks between the two lines, but TeX is always willing to break a page between paragraphs.

You can typeset the thing as a single paragraph, with the bonus of additional markup, which is a good thing, because you might change your mind about the typesetting of such objects and littering your typescript with formatting instruction is evil.

If we make a single two-line paragraph, we can tell TeX that there is an infinite penalty for breaking a page between those lines. We want that the first line is typeset flush left and the second one centered, so we can set the `\leftskip` and the `\rightskip` to infinitely stretchable glue and override it with “more infinite” glue in the first line.

I also add some vertical space above and below each step.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\step}[2]{% #1 = step number, #2 = centered text
  \par
  \addvspace{\topsep}% some vertical space above
  \begingroup % make local settings
  \interlinepenalty=10000 % no page break between lines
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% no indentation in the first line
  \setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt}% don't flush left the last line
  \leftskip=0pt plus 1fil  % infinitely stretchable glue at the left
  \rightskip=0pt plus 1fil % infinitely stretchable glue at the right
  Step #1\hfill\break % override those glues in the first line
  #2\par % the second line (centered)
  \endgroup
  \addvspace{\topsep}% some vertical space
}

\begin{document}

\step{1}{chi-squared-test (assuming data is normal)}

\step{2}{chi-squared-test (assuming data is normal) and some words}

\step{3}{chi-squared-test}

\end{document}
```

[image]